# Data transmission method via LAN simultaneously to multiple users

Tags: c#, networking, lan

I am working on a Battleship game project, played with 2 players on 2 different machine, communicating via LAN using client server architecture. I want to have server handle the game logic, while client handle the game UI.

My problem is related to data transmission between server and the 2 clients. Right now the server can transmit data to 2 clients but one client gets the data later than the other (client No.1 gets "2/2 Players connected" first then client No.2 gets it). I have something like this:

```
foreach (Socket client in clientSockets) {
        string msg = "2/2 Players Connected";
        client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg));
}
```

I also came across the Observer pattern and tried to use it. But from my understanding, the `Notify()` method still uses the `foreach` statement.

I also thinked of using 2 queues for 2 players, which might somewhat mitigate the problem.

So my questions are:

- Are there any other ways to transmit data to 2 players simultaneously?
- Also clarify some things that I misunderstand :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The two thoughts that come to mind are to create threads for the actual sending or to use IP multicasting.

Comment: For the IP multicasting I can understand the concept but not sure how to implement it.
Also what do you mean by create threads for the actual sending?

Comment: I’ve not done it with .NET before when it comes to multicasting. I’m guessing the almighty Google may be able to help.

Comment: Right now, the Socket.Send() method is a blocking call so it sends to the first client in the array and then the next. Instead you should spin up a thread and have it send to the client. What this will do is create a thread per client. The other option is to use Socket.SendAsync and after all data is sent wait for the Task objects to show as completed.  I may be able to hack together a sample later (on mobile, ATM).

Comment: Cool, I understand. I will try to implement it. Thanks a lot, Armstrong